# Which event to be used to detect click event from view pager adapter in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

### What I am doing:

1. I have a `ViewPager`, where i add images to `ImageView` in
   every `View` that I create
2. At the same time I am setting a `TAG` value to it
3. I am using `Activities`

### What i want to do:

1. At the runtime when I click on the particular view I want to get the
   value I selected in tag for the clicked adapter view
2. How to achieve this

---

***Current code:***

```
public class AdptAtomicSongGallery extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        String godName;
        LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> arrLst;
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map;

        public AdptAtomicSongGallery(Context context, LinkedList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> arrLst) {
            this.context = context;
            this.arrLst=arrLst;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrLst.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }




        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LinearLayout selFavGodsContainer;

            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map=arrLst.get(position);

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_atomic_song_gallery, container,false);

            txtSongNameId= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongNameId);

            txtSongNameId.setTag(<!-----Myvalue---->)

                }
            });*/

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i sum everything up. You want a onClick event if a user clicks the view, and you want the tag value from the `txtSongNameId` right?

If yes. Just set an `onClickListener` to your `itemView`.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //you can get the txtSongNameId view like this here:
        (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSongNameId);
        //or you declare it final outside and use it like these here:
        txtSongNameId.getTag()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also i found out  Adapterview click is not available for view pager -- wired, so required we have to use interface callback to achieve it.